# use fade toggle to hide all other div classes but the one from the select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use a `<select>` to show a list of languages help pdf guides. I want to fade toggle all the other pdf links when someone selects on the language option. Here is what I have put together so far; but it's not working and i need to use classes instead of ids.

```
 <select id="load">
   <option>english</option>
   <option>spanish</option>
   <option>italian</option>
 </select>

<h1> help text one </h1>
 <ul class="content-list">
   <li> english</li>
   <li> spanish</li>
   </ul>

<h1> help text two </h1>
 <ul class="content-list">
   <li> english</li>
   <li> italian</li>
 </ul>


 <h1> help text three </h1>
 <ul class="content-list">
   <li> english</li>
 </ul>
```

js

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#load").change(function(event) {
      var id= "#"+this.value;
        $(".content-lists").filter(":not("+id+")").hide();
        $(id).fadeToggle("slow", "linear");//This will toggle div based on the selected option
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you've got a number of issues:

- You'll want to use `class` instead of `id`, as you're going to have multiple items that are "english", "spanish", etc.
- You'll want to use `fadeIn` rather than `fadeToggle`, since you've already hidden the others
- You didn't put a `class` (or an `id`) on your list items
- Your class is "content-list" not "content-lists"
- You'll want to select the individual `li`s not `content-list` itself
- You didn't put quotes around the selector inside of the `:not()`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5cea/)

HTML:

```
<select id="load">
   <option>english</option>
   <option>spanish</option>
   <option>italian</option>
</select>

<h1> help text one </h1>
<ul class="content-list">
   <li class="english"> english</li>
   <li class="spanish"> spanish</li>
</ul>

<h1> help text two </h1>
<ul class="content-list">
   <li class="english"> english</li>
   <li class="italian"> italian</li>
</ul>

<h1> help text three </h1>
<ul class="content-list">
   <li class="english"> english</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#load").change(function(event) {
        var class1= "."+this.value;
        $(".content-list li").filter(":not('"+class1+"')").hide();
        $(class1).fadeIn("slow", "linear");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I am sorry I messed up the code as i was typing in my example. This was a huge time saver. I am def new to javascript !! thnaks everyone !!

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your current code. Probably you can try this way:-

#### HTML

```
<select id="load">
        <option value="english">english</option>
        <option  value="spanish">spanish</option>
        <option  value="italian">italian</option>
    </select>
```

#### JS

```
$("#load").change(function (event) {
    var id = this.value;
    $(".content-list li").filter(function () {
        if ($(this).text().trim() === id) $(this).fadeIn("slow");
        else return $(this)
    }).fadeOut("slow");
}).change();
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zzhKs/)

1. Your class mismatch `.content-lists` v/s `.content-list`
2. Looking for id which is not there. So look for `li` text based on your current markup
3. Provide value to options, else this might not work in IE.

If you can use classnames for your `li` event more easier

#### Html

```
<select id="load">
    <option value="english">english</option>
    <option value="spanish">spanish</option>
    <option value="italian">italian</option>
</select>

<h1> help text one </h1>

<ul class="content-list">
    <li class="english">english</li>
    <li class="spanish">spanish</li>
</ul>

<h1> help text two </h1>

<ul class="content-list">
    <li class="english">english</li>
    <li class="italian">italian</li>
</ul>
 <h1> help text three </h1>

<ul class="content-list">
    <li class="english">english</li>
</ul>
```

#### JS

```
$("#load").change(function (event) {
        var cls = '.' + this.value;
        $(".content-list li")
            .filter(':not(' + cls + ' )') //Filter out all lis but the selected one
            .fadeOut("slow", function ()  { //Fade them out
                   $(cls).fadeIn("slow"); // in the fade complete call back fadeIn the selected one
        });
    }).change();
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fxKqk/)